# Como redirecionar URL de um Popup?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic, ionic-popup

Eu quero que quando clica no botão "ok", que ele vá para a template '/home', após fechar o modal. Segue abaixo o código do popup:

```
    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
     title: '<b>Pedido Enviado</b>',
     subTitle: '<b>Aguarde o número do pedido no seu email. Tempo estimado para entrega de 25 a 35 min</b>',
     buttons:[
        {
           text: 'OK',
           type: 'button-assertive',
           onTap: function(e){
              window.localStorage.clear();
              $scope.modal.hide();
              templateUrl: '/home'
           }
        }
     ]
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `$ionicPopup.alert( ... )` vai retornar uma promise pra `alertPopup`. 
Você pode usar então `alertPopup.then(function(){ ... })` para chamar o redirecionamento dentro desse escopo, ao invés de resolver pelo `onTap`. Por exemplo:

```
  var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
     title: 'Pedido Enviado',
     subTitle: 'Aguarde o número do pedido no seu email. Tempo estimado para entrega de 25 a 35 min',
     okText: 'Ok', // texto do botão, conforme a documentação
     okType: 'button-assertive'
  });

  // após clicar no botão, automaticamente fecha o popup e executa a ação dentro da função abaixo.
  alertPopup.then(function(){
    $state.go('home'); // ou $location.path('/home'), conforme você estiver trabalhando. É importante notar que tem que injetar o serviço $state ou $location no seu controller
  });
```

Comment: Valeu pela informação e exemplo @thiago-ferezim....seu exemplo deu certo....peguei de novo pra estudar e agora entendi a burrice que estava fazendo, mas valeu mesmo